# Hiding Columns Conditionally While Using Page Breaks in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

We would like to hide a column on a page when that column contains no data or 0 value/total for that page.

Here's some example data:

Department is a row group and Macs/PCs is a column group/Pivot.

```
| Department | Macs | PCs |
---------------------------
| Accounting | 0    | 10  |
| Creative   | 10   | 0   |
```

We have a page break on department. For the Accounting page we would like to hide the Macs column and on the Creative page we would like to hide the PCs column.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with the help of a List. And group the list by Department and add the page break there.

Then add your matrix with a row group on Department and with a Column group on your product. Sum your count field.

Just make sure your dataset does not have any zeros.

For a simple dataset as:

```
select
*
from (
    values
    ('Accounting','PC',10),
    ('Creative','PC',10),
    ('Accounting','Mac',11),
    ('Creative','Mac',20)
) x (Department, Product,Total)
```

And a ssrs report setup like this:

[image: SSRSList Group]

You should get the output you want. For more detailed help please supply a sample of your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but looking at the example I provided above, Accounting only has PCs and Creative only has Macs. Once we group PCs and Macs by Department, we want to hide the column that contains zeros for each department.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a formula to the Visibility property of the column group. Something like: 
`iif(IsNothing(Fields!TotalMachines.Value) OR SUM(Fields!TotalMachines.Value) = 0, true, false)`